# Laravel 5.5 CRUD on Chrome

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, crud

I am currently trying to run the program after I have successfully created all the necessary CRUD files. Note that I am following this tutorial [here](https://www.5balloons.info/tutorial-simple-crud-operations-in-laravel-5-5/).

However, I am facing problem in trying to run the sites from my cmd. I tried `taskmanager.dev` but Chrome returned 'This site can’t be reached'.

May I know, is the any specific ways for me to run the site on xampp?

I am using Windows.

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Did you add `taskmanager.dev` to hosts file?

Comment: Can you just open up Bash and run `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Did you setup your virtual host in xampp/apache/conf/extra? Did you add `127.0.0.1 taskmanager.dev` to your hosts file?

Comment: Yes. I did. But this time, whenever I tried connecting to taskmanager.dev, Chrome will return "Your connection is not private". 

I tried using Bash and run `php artisan serve`, I managed to open the Laravel main page from 'http://localhost:8000/'. How do I proceed to view the CRUD files that I have created from there?

Comment: Assuming you setup routing correctly. Navigate to them. localhost:8000/whatever-your-url-is. I recommend you follow my answer / the tutorial details. If you are struggling still I would recommend you watch laracast videos. They'll help you get up an running the fastest. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017. The first video in particular will answer your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've managed to run the site. May I know, from the login page, how do I redirect straight to the view page? Because at the moment, after logging in, I will have to type manually the page that I wish to view in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure the guy who made the tutorial is using [valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet).

Just use `php artisan serve` and you will be able to connect to your site on `localhost`.

But if you really want to use `taskmanager.dev` do the following:

1. Open the `hosts` file, which is lotcated @  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
2. Add `127.0.0.1   taskmanager.dev` at the bottom

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. However, when I tried connecting to the site this time, Chrome returned "Your connection is not private". 

When I use `php artisan serve`, I can connect to the Laravel main page. How do I view the one that I have created in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow their [installation tutorial](https://www.5balloons.info/how-to-install-laravel-5-5-with-xampp/) closely. It sounds like you may not have configured the server correctly.

For me, I have to edit my VHosts file which is in: 
`C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

And to edit my hosts file I need to go to:
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

If all else fails you can always just run `php artisan serve` in bash to launch your app.

But I would recommend going through these instructions again:

**XAMPP Virtual Host**

We need to configure XAMPP Virtual Host to set the document root to correct directory of laravel project and to also assign a name to the project by which we will be accessing it in browser.

Navigate and open file /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf file and uncomment the line that includes the virtual host file.

`# Virtual hosts`

`Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Navigate and open file /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and include following Virtual host entry in this file.

```
# VirtualHost for TASKMANAGER.DEV
<VirtualHost taskmanager.dev:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\taskmanager\public"
ServerAdmin taskmanager.dev
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\taskmanager">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this entry our apache is listening to taskmanager.dev, but we also have to edit our hosts file to include an entry for the new domain.

Edit file /etc/hosts and add following entry to that file.

`127.0.0.1  taskmanager.dev`

Restart your apache and access taskmanager.dev on your browser you should be able to see this screen.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 63 now enforces .dev domains via HTTPS. Follow this article : https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https to know more.

I've changed to *`.test`* for my valet domains. Hope this helps. Thank you.